Selenium Chromdriver Tests on TeamCity is loading indefinitely
I want to run my Selenium test in TeamCity and I'm using ChromeDriver for initialization. When I click "run" in TeamCity, the test starts loading but as soon as it reaches the ChromeDriver in the setup the build just keeps loading indefinitely and nothing happens. There is no error message it just keeps loading and it seems like it doesn't enter the test. Strangely it works fine locally. It's coded in C#.
Here is a picture of the build log in TeamCity:
       private static ChromeDriverService instance = null;
       
       public static ChromeDriverService Instance
       {
           get
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Instance start");
               if (instance == null)
               {
                   instance = new ChromeDriverService();
               }
               Console.WriteLine("Instance end");
               return instance;
           }
       }
       
       public IWebDriver Driver = null;
       
       public ChromeDriverService()
       {
           if (instance != null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
       }
       
       private IWebDriver InitializeWebDriver()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("InitializeWebDriver start");
           if (Driver != null) return Driver;
           ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
           options.AddArgument("headless");
           options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
           options.AddArgument("disable-search-engine-choice-screen");
           new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
           Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
           Console.WriteLine("InitializeWebDriver end");
           return Driver;
       }


I would axe the instance and ChromeDriverSerivce() stuff.  Doesn't look like you are using it and your new ChromeDriver(options); call is going to create its own.  Not sure that's related at all to your problem, though.
